# Avoid returning last evaluated expression in anonymous function within purrr map call

Tags: r, anonymous-function, purrr

Consider this:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl) %>%
  map(
    function(x) {
      cat("*****HEAD******\n")
      print(head(x))
      cat("*****TAIL******\n")
      print(tail(x))
    }
  )
```

Which returns:

```
*****HEAD******
[1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1
*****TAIL******
[1] 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
*****HEAD******
[1] 6 6 4 6 8 6
*****TAIL******
[1] 4 4 8 6 8 4
$`mpg`
[1] 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4

$cyl
[1] 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

How do I avoid returning the last evaluated expression (i.e., `tail(x)`)? My desired output would be:

```
*****HEAD******
[1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1
*****TAIL******
[1] 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
*****HEAD******
[1] 6 6 4 6 8 6
*****TAIL******
[1] 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

I experimented with `return(NULL)`, `return(NA)` and `return(invisible(x))` but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `walk()` instead of `map()`

```
capture <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl) %>%
  walk(
    function(x) {
      cat("*****HEAD******\n")
      print(head(x))
      cat("*****TAIL******\n")
      print(tail(x))
    }
  )
# *****HEAD******
#   [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1
# *****TAIL******
#   [1] 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
# *****HEAD******
#   [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6
# *****TAIL******
#   [1] 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append `%>% invisible` to the end of the pipeline.  It will still return the same result but will do it invisibly so entering it will not show any result.

```
mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl) %>%
  map(
    function(x) {
      cat("*****HEAD******\n")
      print(head(x))
      cat("*****TAIL******\n")
      print(tail(x))
    }
  ) %>% 
  invisible
```

giving:

```
*****HEAD******
[1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1
*****TAIL******
[1] 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
*****HEAD******
[1] 6 6 4 6 8 6
*****TAIL******
[1] 4 4 8 6 8 4
```